# Pullback of a Zariski Sheaf to the Etale SIte.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grothendieck-topologies

Suppose $F$ is a sheaf on the *big* etale site of a scheme $S$ (i..e, where the objects are all schemes over $S$).
If we restrict $F$ to the small Zariski site of $S$ and then pull it back to the *small* etale site, do we get the restriction of $F$ to the small etale site?

Comment: What do you mean by pull back? The small Zariski site embeds in the small étale site so the functor goes the other way.

Comment: Yes, but the convention is that the map of sites is in the direction opposite to that of the functor, just as in the case of ordinary topological spaces.

Comment: In your terminology, I should say "push forward".

Comment: Ah, so you mean the left Kan extension? Anyway, whatever you mean, it seems clear to me that the answer must be no. You should be able to find a counterexample by considering the case where $S$ is the spectrum of a field.

Comment: Unrelated to the math at hand, please use [markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format text instead of `$\textit$`. I've made the adjustment to your post this time.